# Cannot load DLL-- FileNotFound?

Tags: c#

image ==  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUDS8.png

Code :

```
public void loadDLLs()
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\modules");
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@""+System.Environment.CurrentDirectory+"\\modules", "*.dll");
       foreach (string STR in filePaths)
       {
           String nameOfDll = Path.GetFileName(STR).Split('.')[0];
            Assembly MyDALL = Assembly.Load(STR);
            Type MyLoadClass = MyDALL.GetType(nameOfDll + "." + nameOfDll);
            Command obj = (Command)Activator.CreateInstance(MyLoadClass);
           commands.Add(obj);
          }
    }
```

The error here is Assembly.Load();
I've tried loading it with its full path and just modules\\Speach.dll
Nothing seems to work.

Comment: The key is probably `or one of its dependencies`.  Use the fusion logs to get a better idea of what is missing: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

Comment: I looked up my HRESULT and it was something to do with invalid characters. Thing is the DLL doesnt have any of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong method to load an assembly given a filename.
The string passed to [`Assembly.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh(v=vs.110).aspx) is `The long form of the assembly name.`
Something like:

```
"SampleAssembly, Version=1.0.2004.0, Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=8744b20f8da049e3"
```

Instead you need to use [Assembly.LoadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Assembly.LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public void loadDLLs()
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\modules");
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@""+System.Environment.CurrentDirectory+"\\modules", "*.dll");
   foreach (string STR in filePaths)
   {
        String nameOfDll = Path.GetFileName(STR).Split('.')[0];
        Assembly MyDALL = Assembly.LoadFile(STR);
        Type MyLoadClass = MyDALL.GetType(nameOfDll + "." + nameOfDll);
        Command obj = (Command)Activator.CreateInstance(MyLoadClass);
        commands.Add(obj);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes! I love you!!

But now the Type value is null-- I wonder what that could be.

Comment: Can't check of course, but again it could be a possible problem with the string passed. In GetType you need the full qualified type name (IE. Namespace + class name, for example "System.String". )